# Java swing UI rendering difference?

Tags: java, swing, java-9, java-11

My tool was using Java 9. Last week i moved to Java 11 for LTS Support. There is difference in letter "w" rendered in Java 9 and 11. I am using JTable swing component. The below one is the Java 8 rendering

[image]

The below one is Java 11 rendering.

[image]

Can you please help me root cause this issue? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is related to this bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217731

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I have tried with latest java 11.0.4 , issue still exists. 11.0.6 is still not available for download.

Comment: Note that the linked bug report also mentions a workaround.